# 10k tools: all headers in the deleted tab have an incorrect tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, tooltips, wording

See:

[image: 'Questions deleted (not by owner) in the date range, by delete date']

> Questions deleted (not by owner) in the date range, by delete date

^^***LIES***! That list shows questions **and** answers.

It should, instead, be something like:

> Posts deleted (not by owner) in the date range, by delete date

The same incorrect wording is used for **all headings** on that page! (ie. *Most votes*, *Recent votes*, *Recently Undeleted*.)

BTW - if you want to see for yourself, it's at: http://[site.com]/tools?tab=delete

---

I presume this is because the 'template' from the 'close' tab is used for the 'delete' tab as well - only questions can be *closed*, but *anything* can be deleted!!

Comment: Don't know if this is a bug or feature-request; worded to sound like feature request.

Comment: Personally I'd change to bug, as it's a problem with the site, in that it states "question yadda blah", and it should be "questions and answers yadda blah". Feature-request is when something is working as normal/is ok and you want it changing (or something entirely new).

Comment: @James changed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely right - probably including your supposition about how it came to be. Fixed next build.

Comment: I see it's fixed, but only for the `Recently (Un)Deleted` - can it also be fixed for the `Most votes` and `Recent votes` please?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ next build, sure